# "Fast" way to measure code execution time

Tags: performance, fortran, profiling, benchmarking

I have some subroutines in my code whos execution time I need to measure. Let's assume the routines are called somewhere from 10-100 times per second in the extreme case. There are many ways to measure time in Fortran, but due to the frequency of the calls I need the one that incurs the lowest amount of overhead.

The time measurement itself does not need to be super accurate, as I'm not interested in the cases when the subroutines take a few milliseconds or less, but rather when they spike to 50ms or more (which is when I need to take counter-action and re-balance some things internally).

The code is parallelized using MPI+OpenMP, so `MPI_Wtime()` would be the easiest way, but I guess this one has a pretty large cost associated to it? My guess for a good solution would be `system_clock()`. Does anyone know if it's "safe" (performance-wise) to call this 50-100 times per second?

Comment: *I guess this one has a pretty large cost associated to it? My guess for a good solution would be system_clock()*  When it comes to performance measurement data trumps guesses every time.  If this is a matter of concern to you why haven't you measured it already ?

Comment: You are right in what your saying. The thing is I fear the construction of a code snippet to measure the impact of the different timing routines lends itself to by dominated by compiler optimizations and things like that.
Measuring the impact in a real-life testcase with the actual code would require burning several hundred-thousand core-hours, which is quite suboptimal. Therefore I was hoping someone might have some experience with this question.

Comment: Why don't you setup a profiler, do a batch of (100,000 or more?) operations, an only then measure the time?

Comment: Follow Rodigo's suggestion.  Most, if not all, compilers come with profilers.  With gfortran on linux/FreeBSD, use the -pg option and the gprof program to decipher the output.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I did not say that you can't derive that data from a well-crafted test. You are 100% correct in that. The thing is I doubt my abilities to set up such a test, which produces correct data unobstructed from any mis-design of the test ;)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark About the Kernel: Yes, I know that optimizing the thing that takes the majority of the time is the way to go, I spent just the last 3 weeks to speed-up the code by ~5%(which is huge for a code that's used for >100mio core hours per year). But now imagine the Kernel takes just 0.5% longer using the "wrong" timing function, don't you agree that's the cheapest optimization you'll ever get just to switch the way you measure the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system_clock` is likely significantly cheaper than `cpu_time`, and has much better precision.

For GFortran on Linux, I vaguely recall I once tested by calling it in a loop, and `system_clock` took on the order of 50 ns per call.

For GFortran on Linux, `system_clock` is a wrapper around `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)`, (which on Linux uses a vDSO and not a real syscall so it's very very fast) and so is `omp_get_wtime` in libgomp (the OpenMP runtime library that GFortran uses), so the performance for both of these should be more or less the same.

I'm not sure how `MPI_Wtime` is implemented on common MPI implementations, but it wouldn't surprise me if it's the same.

Comment: I have found the following statement in the Cray Fortran compiler manual:
`A call to the SYSTEM_CLOCK intrinsic subroutine with the COUNT argument present translates into the inline instructions that directly access the hardware clock register. [...] The CPU_TIME subroutine obtains the value of its argument from the getrusage system call. Its execution time is significantly longer than for the SYSTEM_CLOCK routine, but the values returned are closer to those used by system accounting utilities.`
So your statement about `system_clock` being cheaper appears to be correct.